# radiogroup is not accepting the radiobutton

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

actually i am trying to add a radiobutton in radiogroup but its not getting adding,instead  the radiobutton is getting added at the end of the screen i.e .below the layout ,out of screen.actually i have added one button that got added but the same i am doing for the second button ..then its nit adding up in radiogroup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:context=".PaymentActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="373dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="628dp"
        android:text="PAYMENT DETAILS"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="555dp"
        android:text="CHOOSE THE PAYMENT MODE"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="269dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="269dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="209dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="477dp"
            android:text="DEBIT CARD"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="CREDIT CARD" />


    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is there, you just can't see it because of this line in second to last radio button

```
android:layout_marginBottom="477dp"
```

Delete it and you'll see your button.

A word of advice - don't use such hardcoded values, especially with a relative layout. With relative layout, you can set where every view is supposed to be with `layout_above`, `layout_below` and etc. If you use hardcoded values, at least put your `RelativeLayout` into `ScrollView` so that you could scroll and see all your view elements.